# What settings is happening in the background when lombok is installed for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, lombok, neovim

There is this [setup](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide) for lombok in Eclipse... What is happening here? What setup values are modified to what? How can I check these changes?

The reason behind my question is that I want to use NeoVim for java and NeoVim uses Eclipse's language server. If something works in Eclipse will work with Neovim. But, this GUI installer is out of my expertise.